# Join data with filename in Spark / PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading in data from a number of S3 files in PySpark. The S3 keys contain the calendar date that the file was created and I'd like to do a join between the data and that date. Is there any way to do a join between the lines of data in files and filenames?

Comment: I'll not say "Welcome to SO!" , but this is a very low quality question. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and what you have tried so far!

Comment: I don't have a problem with code I've written. I am asking a question about whether something is possible in an API. How do you suggest I provide an example for something that might not be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I overwrote the LineRecordReader Hadoop class so that it included the filename in each line, then overwrote TextInputFormat to use my new LineRecordReader.

Then I loaded the file using the newAPIHadoopFile function.

Links:
LineRecordReader: http://tinyurl.com/linerecordreader 
TextInputFormat:  http://tinyurl.com/textinputformat 
newAPIHadoopFile: http://tinyurl.com/newapihadoopfile

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to the dataframe that contains the file name, I use this to identify the source of each row after merging them later:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

filename = 'myawesomefile.csv'

df_new = df.withColumn('file_name', lit(filename))
```

Comment: I was using an RDD, though. I might have been able to switch the code over to using dataframes, but I've not looked much into Spark SQL.